# Only ternary operator works here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, ternary-operator

I am a beginner to React. I just tried the following code:

```
class Contact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="authorization">
        <h1>
          { 
            if (this.state.authorized) {
             'Contact'
            } else {
             'Enter the Password'
            } 
          }     
        </h1>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I have put a JS if-else code in between a pair of curly braces {}, because I read it on 
[Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) that

> You can put any valid JavaScript expression inside the curly braces in JSX.

But the above code just didn't work. But if I replace it with a ternary operator:

```
<h1>
  { this.state.authorized ? 'Contact' : 'Enter the Password' }
</h1>
```

it works! Is that there are some situations under which I can only use ternary operator but not usual JS if-else statement?

Answer (score 3):

A ternary expression is an expression.  An if statement is a statement.  A statement is not an expression.

The important difference here between an expression and a statement is that an expression returns a value.

Comment: Or, to be more precise, an expression *evaluates* to a value.

Answer (score 2):

If-else doesn't work in JSX, per the spec of the language: https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Answer (score 1):

If you really what to do this, you could use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Here is an example:

```
class Contact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="authorization">
        <h1>
        { 
          (() => {
            if (this.state.authorized) {
              return 'Contact'
            } else {
              return 'Enter the Password'
            } 
          })()
        }     
        </h1>
    )
  }
}
```

But this is not standard, you are better off creating a variable before the return statement and adding it using a construct like this: `{ someVar }`.